# Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. What is the reason for this error?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I got this error when I try to import Switch from react-router-dom

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {gql} from "@apollo/client";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import './app.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Login from './components/pages/Login';
import Register from './components/pages/Register';
function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router>
     
              <Switch>
                  <Route path="/"><Home/></Route>
                  <Route path="/login"><Login/></Route>
                  <Route path="/register"><Register/></Route>
              </Switch>

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: If you are using react-router version 6, `Switch` ha been removed.

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer. The reason was they have removed Switch from react-router-dom. Instead of Switch I used Routes.It worked.Thank you